Find the maximum of a combinatorial problem
We use $[s]$ to denote a set of all positive integers not larger than $s$, namely $\{1,2,\cdots, s\}$.
Given two positive integers $n$ and $k$, denote $G$ as the set of all functions mapping from $[n]$ to $[k]$. $F$ is a subset of $G$ and there don't exsist two positive integers $i,j\in [n]$ such that for any value $p, q \in [k]$, there is a function $f\in F$ where $f(i)=p$ and $f(j)=q$. Find the maximum of $|F|$.

A lower bound of the maximum is $(k-1)^{n-1}(n+k-1)$ which is constructed by the union of $$\{f:f(i)<k,\,i \in [n]\}$$ and $$\bigcup_{t=1}^n \{f:f(t)=k,\,f(i)<k,\,i\in [n]\backslash \{t\} \}$$ where the first set has a cardinality of $(k-1)^n$ and the second has $n(k-1)^{n-1}$. And If we make $p=q=k$, it is impossible to have a function in our construction such that $f(i)=f(j)=k$ simultaneously, which satisfies the requirement. But I am not sure if this lower bound is tight.
